# On click of button group how to identify which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a button group consist of four buttons,what i am trying to do is whenever user clicks on any button i want fetch its text

- I am doing something like this

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var button_text = $('#oneMonth').text();
  alert(button_text)
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" align="center">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sevenDays">Seven Days</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="oneMonth">One Month</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sixMonths">Six Months</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="oneYear">One Year</button>
</div>
```

I am doing something like this but its not the right way as i have to put each and every id of button to get the text

I want to do like if user clicks on any button just get the text of that button only

Comment: `$(this).text()`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` keyword instead of specific selector in alert to get the text of the clicked button

```
var button_text = $(this).text();
```

This will always give the text of the button with id `oneMonth`

```
$('#oneMonth').text();
```

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var button_text = $(this).text();
  alert(button_text)
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" align="center">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sevenDays">Seven Days</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="oneMonth">One Month</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sixMonths">Six Months</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="oneYear">One Year</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the this jQuery to your code. Here is a working snippet:

```js
var buttons = $("button");
buttons.click(function() {
  $(".display__text").text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" align="center">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sevenDays">Seven Days</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="oneMonth">One Month</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sixMonths">Six Months</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="oneYear">One Year</button>
</div>

<div class="display__text"></div>
```